# How to know the mount path of router on express?

Tags: node.js, express, router

I'm using express' [Router](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router) on a web application.
I'm adding the routers the usual way:

```
app.use(router, '/myroutehere/');
```

The handlers for each router don't have any idea of where they have been "mounted" (different files, different concerns, etc.). This has worked ok until now that I need to create a ToC for one of the routers (and the content is dynamically generated). I'm using `url.resolve` to handle the relative paths, but I'm missing the initial part of the url (otherwise the links will resolve to `/` instead of `/myrouter/`).

Is there a way to know the mount path of a router without hardcoding it in different places?

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
  // Need to know the mount path here or a way to resolve relative links
  // to the mount path and make them absolute to the app
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about "router.mountpath"?

> The app.mountpath property contains one or more path patterns on which
>   a sub-app was mounted

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.mountpath

**Upd.** Ok, you need: `<req.route.path>, <req.baseUrl>, <req.originalUrl>`

Comment: That only seems to work with express apps and not the Router object :( I'm getting undefined right now but will review my code again just in case.

Comment: Ok, you need:
`<req.route.path>, <req.baseUrl>, <req.originalUrl>`

Comment: req.baseUrl seems to be the right one although it is missing the ending / in my case.
Can you update your answer so I can mark it as the valid one? Thank you very much!